# Load Libraries the CodeIgniter-way

Tags: php, codeigniter, load, shared-libraries

I have my own little MVC and would like to load my libraries in the same way, codeigniter does:

```
Foo {

    $load = Load();

    function temp() {
        $this->load('baa');
        $this->baa->method();
    }

}
```

so `Load()` makes an instance of `Baa()` and assigns it to `Foo`'s properties. Would be great if someone could tell me how to asign this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever look to system/core/Loader.php file which inside of CodeIgniter package? Complete and best solution is that I think.

Comment: CI_Loader returns $this. load() is in system/core/Config.php but I don't understand how it's working.

Comment: in system/ocre/Common.php there is a method "load_class()" you could look that

Comment: Thanks. I think it's too high for me :-). Maybe someone knows an easy way to do it but I guess there is none.

Comment: @user2365069 honestly, if it is *too high* for you maybe you should not be making your own untested framework. Why are you not using what has already been made and tested? Not many reasons to re-invent the wheel. Besides CI does not properly follow MVC so it's a bad thing to try to duplicate and learn from. Just my two cents =)

Comment: I needed a tiny framework that I understand to use in WordPress and found http://youtu.be/CGiIVQPaOJQ which made a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot understands how CI works, you should realy look for another solution for your problem.

What you writed is not PHP.

```
class Foo {

    //public $load = Load(); //it is not possible, must be a constant value (string, int, bool ..)

    public function temp() {
        //$this->load('baa'); //not possible
        //$this->baa->method();
    }

}
```

Before asking for CodeIgniter-way, you should learn PHP and his POO.

Anyway i give you what you asked, simplified:

libraries/somelib.php

```
class Somelib {
    public $foo = "ok";
}
```

index.php

```
class Core {

    public function load($library) {
       //library already loaded
       if( property_exists($this, $library) )
        {
            return $this->{$library};
        }

        //library file not found
        if( ! file_exists("libraries/$library.php") )
        {
            exit('library not found');
        }

        //include the library file
        include("libraries/$library.php");

        //instanciate the library dynamicly
        $class = new $library();

        //assign the class object to a Core class property
        $this->{$library} = $class;
    }   
}

//This class inherit Core methods
class OtherClass extends Core {

    public function some_method() {
        $this->load('somelib');
        echo $this->somelib->foo;
    }
}


$App = new OtherClass();

$App->some_method();
```

Assume `$this` in CI is the Core Class, so it is `$App`.
And OtherClass is some Controller or Method.

if you run index.php, you will see `ok`.